# Can't unzip downloaded file in iOS

Tags: ios, zip, nsurl

I download a zip file via `AFNetworking` and in the end, I have `NSURL *filePath` of that file. I use `SSZipArchive` to unzip that file. But it gives:

> 'failed to open zip file'

and it comes from deep and dirty `C` code, basically no idea why it can't be opened.

This is basically my code:

```
...
completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse * _Nonnull response,
                          NSURL * _Nullable filePath,
                          NSError * _Nullable error) {
        [SSZipArchive unzipFileAtPath:[filePath absoluteString]
                    toDestination:destinationPath];
    }];
...
```

I check if the file really exists at this file path from `Xcode->Devices` and I can see that it is there.

Comment: is it really zip file?

Comment: yes, it is. I can see .zip extension in Devices.

Comment: extension doesnt mean that it is actually zip compressed file

Answer (score 0):

Finally I solved it.
The solution is [here](https://github.com/ZipArchive/ZipArchive/issues/31).

To sum up: when you convert `NSURL` for a file path to `NSString`, you should use `fileURL.path`, instead of `absoluteString` or anything else.

To achieve the contrary, you should use `[NSURL fileURLWithPath:pathString]`

I changed `[filePath absoluteString]` with `[filePath path]` and it worked.